# Sitefinity: Need to make a PDF available on a very specific URL but can't do it

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I have a website on SiteFinity 4.4. I need to make a document available on a very specific URL, i.e.

http:www.example.com/reports/the-report.pdf

If I just create a directory in the root of the site it does not work (503 error). Also when I try to use the 302Redirect.xml file to redirect the URL to the PDF it does not work either (same error). The link has already been published and has to be exactly as specified. How do I solve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitefinity wouldn't block a folder. Adding a physical folder and dropping that report on the proper place should function, so it probably means you'll have to check your server configuration.

Anyway, the fastest way outside Sitefinity, would be to just create a IIS rewrite rule. Make the http:/www.example.com/reports/the-report.pdf the pattern and redirect them to the url of the document from the sitefinity library.

When you upload a document to the library in sitefinity it gives you an direct url, something like /docs/defaultlibrary/document. You can verify the url by going to content >> documents and files and chose Embed link to this file. That gives you a pop-up with the url.